# Should I change my name as it is the name of an idol?

Tags: naming

I heard:

> The names of the two hills As Safa and al-Marwa signify a stone, that is, an idol. Pagans ran between the two hills in order to touch and kiss Isaf and Naila. the idols, placed there as a means of acquiring luck and good fortune. -- Ibn Warraq, Why I Am Not a Muslim, 2003

I want to know, should I change my name, as Naila is name of idol mentioned in Quran?  We do not worship any idols and have a belief that Allah is one and only one God.  We were unaware of this thing earlier, but now when we got to know this, what should I do?

Will I, or my parents, receive punishment from Allah (SWT) as meaning of my name is mention as idol worship here?

Answer (score 3):

you said "NAILA is name of idol mentioned in quran". Naila is not mentioned in Quran as an idol. May be what you mentioned is from some other source.

Naila is the name of wife of third Caliph, Uthman (r.a) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naila_bint_al-Farafsa

It doesn't matter if some idol in past had this name or not, it is said that there used to be idols in the name of Ibrahim (a.s) and ismaeel (a.s) inside ka'ba before it was cleaned by prophet(s.a).But that doesn't mean we cannot have these names. Names should not have bad meaning, Naila is not having bad meaning so I think no need to change it.

Arabic fatwa site which states that it is ok to have this name and lists number of companions of prophet(s.a) with this name
https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/195325

Comment: the best example is.... The name ["Allah" is the name of moon god](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon-God_Allah) many years before islam came into existence. But...

Comment: Allah being a mood god is used only critics. no basis for this claim. of course, Allah was used before prophet (s.a) by Arab Jews,Christians and polytheist to denote unseen God. Even now Arab christian uses Allah in Arabic Bible.

Comment: they say there are archeological evidences... But "Allah" simply means "The God" thats it,,,

Comment: no archaeological evidence, it is put forward by Christian apologist author Robert Morey. Their purpose is to claim Muslims worship a different God and not the God in Bible.

Comment: Ok.... Thank you so much for your proper guidance and help. Allah is greatest.

Comment: @Ziyad. A very good point. Strangely, there are now Muslims who claim that Muslims worship a different God than the Christians and even want to ban Christians from addressing him as Allah. We live in strange times...